# why does c# list add reference to the variable?

Tags: java, c#

Ok so when I run this function I expect to get a list of linkendlist referencing nodes at each level of a binary tree. However this function returns empty linkendlists for all levels. Could someone tell me why? I have added solution in java as well.

```
        public static void Main()
        {
            BinaryTree t = new BinaryTree(0);

            BinaryTree l1 = new BinaryTree(1);
            BinaryTree l2 = new BinaryTree(2);
            BinaryTree l3 = new BinaryTree(3);
            BinaryTree l4 = new BinaryTree(4);
            BinaryTree l5 = new BinaryTree(5);
            BinaryTree l6 = new BinaryTree(6);

            t.left = l1;
            t.right = l4;

            l1.left = l2;
            l1.right = l3;

            l4.left = l5;
            l4.right = l6;

            List<LinkedList<BinaryTree>> lod = ListOfDepth(t);

            // this will print empty list
            foreach (var item in lod)
            {
                foreach (var lst in item)
                {
                    Console.Write(lst.data);

                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }


}
    public class BinaryTree
    {
        public BinaryTree(int d) { data = d; }
        public BinaryTree() { }
        public int id;
        public int data;
        public BinaryTree left = null;
        public BinaryTree right = null;
}

public static List<LinkedList<BinaryTree>> ListOfDepth(BinaryTree t)
{
    List<LinkedList<BinaryTree>> lst = new List<LinkedList<BinaryTree>>();
    // add current level to lst
    LinkedList<BinaryTree> curLevel = new LinkedList<BinaryTree>();
    curLevel.AddLast(t);
    lst.Add(curLevel); 

    LinkedList<BinaryTree> newLevel = new LinkedList<BinaryTree>();
    while (curLevel.Count > 0)
    {
        BinaryTree curNode = curLevel.First.Value;
        curLevel.RemoveFirst();

        if (curNode.left != null)
        {
            newLevel.AddLast(curNode.left);
        }
        if (curNode.right != null)
        {
            newLevel.AddLast(curNode.right);
        }

        if (curLevel.Count == 0)
        {
            curLevel = newLevel;
            if (newLevel.Count > 0)
            {
                lst.Add(newLevel);
            }
            newLevel = new LinkedList<BinaryTree>();

        }

    }

    return lst;
}
```

Java Version.

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<BinaryTree>> listofDepth(BinaryTree root) {
    ArrayList<LinkedList<BinaryTree>> result = new ArrayList<LinkedList<BinaryTree>>();
    LinkedList<BinaryTree> current = new LinkedList<BinaryTree>();
    if (root != null) {
       current.add(root);
    }

    while (current.size() > 0) {
      result.add(current);
      LinkedList<BinaryTree> parents = current;
      current = new LinkedList<BinaryTree>();

      for (BinaryTree parent : parents) {
         if (parent.left != null) {
            current.add(parent.left);
         }
         if (parent.right != null) {
             current.add(parent.right);
          }
      }

    }
 return result;
}
```

Comment: C#, Java and C++ are three different and very unrelated languages. There are some syntactical similarities but that's it. You can't and should not compare them or their libraries.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: my question is regarding C# references. I have removed the tags referring to c++.

Comment: *here is when I add curLevel to lst, it seem to add curlevel the variable and not what it's referencing..* What does that mean?

Comment: "This is not the case for Java arrayList." Yes it is. You would see the same thing in Java. I suggest you read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html. Note that it's not adding the variable - it's adding the value of the variable, which *is* a reference. Changing just the variable, e.g. `curLevel = null;` wouldn't affect the list.

Comment: `LinkedList<BinaryTree> curLevel` is defenetily reference type and reference will be added to the list, in Java too

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Ok so when I run this function I expect to get a list of linkendlist referencing nodes at each level of a binary tree. However this function returns empty linkendlists for all levels.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I have tried this function in Xamarin Studio, but it returns empty linkendlist. I am going to add more code to see if it clears things up.

Comment: It sounds like you should really do a lot more debugging and diagnostics. Your current code is very confusing, but I'm certain it's just behaving as normal in terms of reference types.

Comment: @JonSkeet:  Could you tell me why the first level is empty? I have a solution here in Java and it seems to do the same thing, but it works according to its author.

Comment: You're creating a linked list, adding an entry to it, and adding that linked list to your result list... then you're immediately removing that first entry from the linked list. So yes, it's empty. We don't really know what you're trying to achieve here, but again, you should step through this in a debugger. If you've ported this from similar code in Java, does that mean you don't know how this code is even *meant* to work?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I am working through a coding problem book that provides the solution in Java. I tried solving it using C# since I want to learn it. I can see where the mistake is now. It was confusing at first indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is obvious. In the Java version of your code, you use a variable `current` from the outside of your method, where you add an item (`root`) to.

In the C# version, you don't have that variable and hence it doesn't get added to the current. Instead, you create a new variable inside your method to add it to. Those are two totally different code blocks.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake typing out the solution in java. There is actually a declaration.

Comment: I have tried the java solution in C# and it seems to work as well. I guess the bug must be some where else and not with my understanding of references.